# Laravel CSS files not found and No styling applied (Apache2 Ubuntu)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

I have a application know as nexthour cms which I am running using apache2 on ubuntu. I have added all the configuration in apache2 and downloaded all the extensions in php. The nexthour appliaction is based on Laravel. The issue is that there is a **server.php** file in the root directory. When I ran this file for the first time it went through some steps for installation of the application. Once those steps were done it showed the application but no styling was being shown. The webpage was only showed text when opening server.php file and when I open links like login it takes me to the login page but no styling is applied. When I checked the css file location from source code it shows the path localhost/server.php/css/thecssfile.css but the file is not found.

When I open the **public directory** all the styling is being applied but the issue here is that it is not able to find the login page when I press login.

When I checked the login page location from **server.php** file it shows as localhost/server.php/login and it opens fine but still without any styling. Remember that server.php is not a directory it is a php file. Where do I find the login file in the folder as server.php is not a directory?

When I checked the login page location from **public/index.php** it is localhost/public/login file is not found and I checked the directory and there is no login file or directory.

What should I do in this case? I can not use the server.php file as there is no styling and I can also not use public/index.php as the login page is not found. Please help me out as I a complete noob in laravel or php and this is a application I have downloaded and not developed. Your help will be highly appreciated if someone could let me know whats happening here.

Update: localhost/public/index.php/login works fine but no styling show up here.

Comment: Don't know this CMS, but usually, you don't use `server.php` in Laravel. Running `php artisan serve` should serve the site from the `public` folder. Since you use Apache, setup a Vhost or point your DocumentRoot to the `public` folder.

Comment: I have pointed the vhost but the issue is that it doesn't find the login file. It finds it when I use server.php

Comment: Does anybody have any idea where will I be able to find the file localhost/server.php/login because server.php is not a directory.

Comment: There is no "login" _file_, it's a route that points to a controller/method

Comment: How do I fix this issue then because I just checked that localhost/public/index.php/login works but localhost/public/login doesn't work.

Comment: Got it All fixed just had to use `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it all fixed just had to use `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to resolve this issue.